# Are there benefits in using the static modifier on functions in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I recently started working with TypeScript and my IDE WebStorm linted me that I could use a static modifier...

```
export default class MyClass {
    public bar(): any {
        // do sth. with instance values
    }

    private foo(a: any, b: any): any {
        // do sth. without instance values, like checking
    }
}
```

Here I would get a warning that `foo(a, b)` could be declared `static`. For now I turned that "warning" off, since I mostly consider liberal use of static as "code-smell", but then again I'm not an expert in TypeScript.

Are there any significant "side-benefits" of using the static modifier? Besides what it does per [definition](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Comment: And for me the code smells when one is defining instance methods that don't (and will not) depend on instance state.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like you alluded to, using the `static` modifier has the main benefit of making class members accessible without having to instantiate the class.

A noteworthy "side-effect" of using a static modifier on a class member in TypeScript is that you will not be able to access that member from a class instance.

```
class Hamburger {
     static beef_percentage: number = 75;
     public tasty: boolean = false;
}

console.log(Hamburger.beef_percentage); // 75
console.log(Hamburger.tasty); // Error

var myHamburger = new Hamburger();
console.log(myHamburger.beef_percentage); // Error
console.log(myHamburger.tasty); // false
```

I suppose that this could be useful in some instances.

If a method is not accessing members from a its instance I recommend making that method static for the sake of clarity concerning the purpose of your class.

Comment: Should 
console.log(myHamburger.beefy); // Error
be 
console.log(myHamburger.beef_percentage); // Error?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your implementation, but by removing an item from the prototype (and not referencing it via the prototype chain) lookup should generally be faster, but that is ultimately up to the engine, and I would imagine would be mostly negligible.

Answer (score 0):

If your method `foo` doesn't depend on `instance` attributes and is more like a `utility` method then there is no point in adding it to each `instance` and better to have it at one place at `class` level